# How to read all textbox values(Map to database fileds) and store them in Database in WPF - MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to WPF and MVVM. After a long invention i got to know how to retrieve data from database and bind it to a itemcontrol/listview/gridview.

But my problem i am not getting how to read bunch of textbox values and store as a  new record in database.

Here is my sample code..

View

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployees}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="4"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="4"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="4"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<!-- For new Employee Details -->
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="FirstName"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="LastName"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Age"/>
        <Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewEmployeeCommand}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

My cs file is

```
    public ObservableCollection<DataAccess.Employee> AllEmployees
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }  

    public EmployeeListViewModel(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
            {
                if (employeeRepository == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("employeeRepository");
                }

                _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
                this.AllEmployees = new ObservableCollection<DataAccess.Employee> 
                                    (_employeeRepository.ListAll());
 }
```

Now how could i store a new employee Firstname, Lastname, Age in database by reading those text boxes..

How to write function for **NewEmployeeCommand** event to read the textboxes( **mapping of textboxes to appropriate datafileds in database**) and store the data in database.

Thanks a Lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Correct answer.

My New entry form in xmal Should be

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Employee.FirstName}"/>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Employee.LastName}"/>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Employee.Age}"/>
        <Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewEmployeeCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My cs file

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  Employee _employee;
  RelayCommand _addNewEmployee;
  EmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

  public Employee Employee
  {
       get
       {
         return _employee;
       }
       set
       {
          _employee = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
        }

  }    

  public void NewEmployeeCommand()
  {
    if(_addNewEmployee == null)
    {
       _addNewEmployee = new RelayCommand( param => NewEmployeeCommandExecute(), 
                                           param => NewEmployeeCommandCanExecute
                                          );
    }
  }

  void NewEmployeeCommandExecute()
  {
         _employeeRepository.Add(Employee); 
         _employeeRepository.Save();
   }

   bool NewEmployeeCommandCanExecute
   {
         get
         {
            return true;
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to use MVVM just need to:

- Create your ViewModel to contain all the properties your View needs
- Bind to those properties in Xaml

For example:

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Employee> AllEmployees {get;private set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  public int? Age {get;set;}  
  public ICommand NewEmployeeCommand {get;set;}

  //You need to connect to this method by using a Delegate/RelayCommand see link below
  public void AddNewEmployee()
  {
    //Add your real code here to actually insert into the db
    var result = InsertEmployeeIntoDatabase(FirstName,LastName,Age);
    //You probably want to add this new employee to the list now ;)
    AllEmployees.Add(result);
    //Now you probably want to reset your fields
    FirstName = null;
    LastName = null;
    Age = null;
  }
}
```

[Click here for an implementation of a delegate command](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

And then just edit your xaml like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployees}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="4"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="4"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="4"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<!-- For new Employee Details -->
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text={Binding FirstName}"/>
        <TextBox Text={Binding LastName}"/>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Age}"/>
        <Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewEmployeeCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass references in the command parameter:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="FirstName"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="LastName"/>
    <Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewEmployeeCommand}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <x:Reference Name="FirstName"/>
                <x:Reference Name="LastName"/>
            </x:Array>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Depending on what kind of event you use you case the parameter and get the values:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = e.Parameter as TextBox[]; //RoutedEvent
TextBox[] textBoxes = parameter as TextBox[]; //If the executed handler provides the parameter

string firstName = textBoxes[0].Text;
string lastName = textBoxes[1].Text;
//create entry; store in DB
```

---

Via binding:

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <local:MyEntry FirstName="{Binding ElementName=FirstName, Path=Text}"
                   LastName="{Binding ElementName=LastName, Path=Text}"/>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

```
MyEntry entry = parameter as MyEntry;
//store in DB
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But will it be a MVVM pattern ?

Comment: I do not know, sorry, i only recently started looking into MVVM. You could create an object in the CommandParameter and bind its values, i think that would be cleaner.

Comment: I added the binding alternative (which is probably similar to what blindmeis was referring to), this requires dependency properties though.

Answer (score 1):

you dont read the Textbox values. you need a NewEmployeeViewModel and bind the TextBoxes to the properties.

EDIT:

just create a class with INotifyPropertyChanged and the Properties you need.

```
public class NewEmployee : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   public string FirstName
   {
     get{return this._firstname;}
     set{this._firstname = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");}
   }
   //... other properties
 }
```

xaml

```
<StackPanel DataContext={Binding MyNewEmployeeProperty}>
    <TextBox x:Name="FirstName" Text={Binding FirstName}/>
    <TextBox x:Name="LastName" Text={Binding LastName}/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Age" Text={Binding Age}/>
    <Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewEmployeeCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @Blindmeis: could your give me some code how to do it ? thank you

Comment: @Blindmeis: Thanks man. But how could i map these text boxes to my Employee Database.

Comment: i dont know your DAL but if you have a method to insert a new row. just fulfill the conditions. you do not map the textboxes to your database. the textboxes are bind to your vm and your vm has all the data you need. do you use NHibernate or another ORM?

Comment: sory little delay .. i am using Linq-to-SQL

Comment: i dont know Linq-to-Sql but i think there are entities too? so maybe you have a entity called EmployeeEntity. if so just map your property data to your entity and call entity.Save() in your New command. if Linq-to-Sql entity implement INotifyProepertyChanged you can bind the entity direct to your view. BTW Jose post a complete sample